# Object function as callback for add_shortcode( ) in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, object

I created a class to build custom post types and I'm trying to include a way to insert specific shortcodes for that post type, but I can't seem to get the callback function for the add_shortcode() to get a function from inside the created object.

I have something similar to this:

```
class custom_post_type {

    public $post_type_name;

    function __construct($id,$options) {
        //builds the custom post type, etc
        $this->post_type_name = $id;
        $shortcode = new build_shortcode($id,$options);
    }

    public function shortcode_handler($atts) {

    return $this->post_type_name;        

    }
}

class build_shortcode {
     function __construct($id,$options) {
           add_shortcode( $options['shortcode_name'] , array(  $id ,'shortcode_handler') );
     }
}

$options = array(); // a bunch of variables would be defined here to use in the classes
$post_type = new custom_post_type('post_type',$options);
```

But when I use the [show-cpt-name] shortcode, it doesn't run the function. 
I know in the Codex they give and example to use a class, like:

```
add_shortcode( $options['shortcode_name'] , array( 'custom_post_type' ,'shortcode_handler'));
```

But this is not what I am looking for, since I wanted the callback function to use values from that particular object created.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: As far I know I don't think is possible. Why you want to pass the id ?

Comment: The $id will be the object name, in this case, 'post_type', as I want to access the function inside $post_type. Outside the class it would be something like $post_type->shortcode_handler($atts);

Comment: I don't think is possible but I am not sure. btw you can't have the same name for a shortcode. So everytime you create an custom_post_type object the same shortcode is created with the same name right ? (in your case show-cpt-name)

Comment: the names of the shortcode would actually be in the $options array, so they wouldn't have the same name as there would also be code to control that, but I left it out as it was not relevant to the question here. I'll update the example code to exemplify how. Thanks!